# Mockito not returning the expected return value

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito

I'm working on a Java project and trying to use Mockito. Here is my test code :

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class TestMainController {
    @MockBean
    MainController mainController;

    @MockBean
    AnotherServiceImpl anotherService;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(mainController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void TestFirstFunctionFor201() throws Exception {
        String req = "<JSON_STRING>";
        when(anotherService.someFunction(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn("Success");
        this.mockMvc.perform(put("/Main/one/").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(req)).andExpect(status().isCreated());
    }
}
```

I have to change the names of course. Here is the controller code :

```
@PutMapping("/Main/one")
    public ResponseEntity<String> firstFunction(@RequestBody RequestObject requestObject){
        String result = anotherService.someFunction(requestOject.getName());
        if(Objects.equals(result, "Success")){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

So I'm mocking `firstFunction` into returning "Success", but I'm not getting the result. Instead, the actual function is being executed. The testcase passed only when `req` is   the appropriate one. In other words the function is not getting mocked.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to mock the **class** or the **method** you want to test. The idea behind mocking is to **mock** your dependencies. Here in your case, the class you want to test is `MainController` and it depends on `AnotherServiceImpl`. It is ok, you have mocked your dependency, so you don't have to mock `MainController`.

Also, here you are doing an *integration test* because of the annotation `@SpringBootTest` that will load all your context. And I guess this is not what you want when using `MockMvc`. You have to use [test slice](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2021/07/12/spring-boot-test-slices) instead with the annotation `@WebMvcTest(MainController.class)`.

Your class should look something like that:

```
@WebMvcTest(TestMainController.class)
public class TestMainController {
    
    @MockBean
    AnotherServiceImpl anotherService;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(mainController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void TestFirstFunctionFor201() throws Exception {
        String req = "<JSON_STRING>";
        when(anotherService.someFunction(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn("Success");
        this.mockMvc.perform(put("/Main/one/").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(req)).andExpect(status().isCreated());
    }
}
```

Comment: If I remove `@SpringBootTest`,  I get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext`.  If I follow your code, I get `java.lang.NullPointerException` in `setup()` function. Btw I autowired the `Maincontroller` since it is used in `setup()`.

Comment: What is the version of spring boot you use?

Comment: Springboot Version 2.4.5.

Comment: Ok, it a version issue. It remain this annotation `@ExtendsWith`. Read this link for more details, or you can upgrade your version. https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/testing/spring-boot-2-junit-5/